# How to set JS source directory in apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, javascript

I am trying to run a very basic webserver for development/debugging. The static HTML seems to be delivered correctly, but it seems that the JavaScript libraries are not being delivered to the browser. The page HTML says something like

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="/lib/json.js"></script>
...
```

Now, I have set up a link for /lib/ in my httpd.conf as:

```
Scriptalias /lib/ "/SomeFolder/lib/"
```

When I do this, it can't fetch the files because this is what I see in my apache error log:

```
... [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /SomeFolder/lib/json.js, referer: http://localhost/SomeSite
```

It seems that apache is not allowing access to the folder, so I add this to httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/SomeFolder/lib/">
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

After this, browsing the page still does not run the JS, instead I see the following error in my apache error log:

```
[error] [client ::1] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/SomeFolder/lib/json.js' failed, referer: http://localhost/SomeSite
```

So now, it seems that apache is trying to run the JS files on the server like a cgi script or something. But I have not made that folder a cgi-bin folder. The only lines where `SomeFolder` is mentioned by name is in these lines in httpd.conf:

```
Scriptalias /lib/ "/SomeFolder/lib/"
<Directory "/SomeFolder/lib/">
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `ScriptAlias`, it is treating everything in that directory like a CGI script.  What you'll want to use instead is `Alias`:

```
Alias /lib "/SomeFolder/lib"
```

Andrew